# UITableView in edit mode - 'Edit' button doesn't change status

Tags: iphone, uitableview, editmode

I have a UIViewController class, with a tableView. In viewDidLoad:

```
UIBarButtonItem *editIcon = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit
                    target:self
                    action:@selector(toggleEditMode)] autorelease];
```

In te method 'toggleEditMode':

```
-(void)toggleEditMode{
if(self.theTable.editing) {
    [theTable setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain];
}
else if ([callsArray count]!=0){
    [theTable setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];
}
```

}

The problem is that the Edit button does not change do 'DONE'. What's missing? I have all the methods declared:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Thanks,

RL

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Why not use `-editButtonItem` of UIViewController directly ? And override `-setEditing:animated:` method.

```
// Assign the system's edit button, 
// it will change style when different edit status.
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

// The editButtonItem will invoke this method.
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (editing) {
         // Execute tasks for editing status
    } else {
         // Execute tasks for non-editing status.
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect.
Just changed if(editing) to if(theTable.editing) because de tableView is an IBOutlet. The class is not inherit from UITableViewController.
Thanks,
RL

Comment: Even though this is an old question it helped me realize I forgot the [super setEditing:editing animated:animated]; line, which is why mine wasn't working. ;) Thank you for posting this.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're only setting the **style** of the button (not its **text**) when you switch modes. You need to do this (or equivalent):

```
-(void)toggleEditMode{
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = self.tableView.editing ? @"Done" : @"Edit";
```

Comment: Why does not work like when a class is inherits from UITableViewController?
Can't I assign the button to the table and work like that?

Answer (score 0):

You sure `callsArray` is not empty ?

Place a breakpoint inside `toggleEditMode` and see what happens there.

**Edit**

Ok, after understanding your question, have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251589/uibarbuttonitemstyledone-does-not-create-blue-buttons-in-navigation-bar-when-cont)

Comment: yes, I'm sure. The table enter in Edit mode, and it works when I delete a row. That's not the problem.
The problem is that the 'Edit' button does not change it's name do 'DONE' has does when the class is a UITableViewController class. Instead, my class is a UIViewController with a table in it.